# Jersey Resource Filter not forwarding request

Tags: rest, resources, filter, jersey

I am working on a Jersey implementation wherein my requirement is to verify and validate the request body and forward it to the REST resource.

The validation and verification are working fine inside registered filter but for forwarding. The request is not getting forwarded to the REST resource. I am unable to figure what is that I am missing. Here is my configuration and code

web.xml

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>com.level3.messaging.producer.auth.PubRequestFilterFactory</param-value>
</init-param>
```

My Resource filter factory

```java
@Component
@Provider
public class PubRequestFilterFactory implements
    ResourceFilterFactory {

    @Autowired
    PublisherRequestFilter publisherRequestFilter;

    @Override
    public List<ResourceFilter> create(AbstractMethod am) {
    return Collections
        .<ResourceFilter> singletonList(publisherRequestFilter);
    }

}
```

My Resource Filter implementation

```java
@Component
@Provider
public class PublisherRequestFilter implements ResourceFilter {      

    @Override
    public ContainerRequestFilter getRequestFilter() {

    return new ContainerRequestFilter() {
        /**
         * Checks if the incoming request is appropriate for the request
         * body. If not throws a web application exception
         */
        @Override
        public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
         // returned request is not gettting forwared.
                            // I was able to debug thru request
        return request;
        }
    };
    }

    @Override
    public ContainerResponseFilter getResponseFilter() {
    return null;
    }

}
```

My REST Resource Implementation

```java
@Component
@Produces("application/xml")
@Path("publish")
@Scope("singleton")
public class Publisher extends MessageResource {     

    @POST
    @Path("event")
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public ProducerResourceResponseWrapper publishEvent(Event event) {
        super.message = event;
        final Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        init(MessagePattern.Event.name());
        publishMessage(startTime);
        return responseWrapper;
    }


    private void publishMessage(Long startTime) {
    String errorMessage = null;
    try {
        final MessageDelegator eventDelegator = new MessageDelegator(
            publisherResourcesDO);
        eventDelegator.delegate();
        if (publisherResourcesDO.getErrorDO() != null) {
        throw new ErrorHandler(publisherResourcesDO.getErrorDO());
        }
        buildResponse(startTime);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        errorMessage = e.getMessage();
        handleException(e);
    } finally {
        auditMessage(startTime, errorMessage);
    }

    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "The request is not getting forwarded to the REST resource"? Is the resource method not called at all? What response do you see on the client?

Comment: The resource method is not called at all. I see a 400 bad request. I did some more research. It gets called if the Content-type and Accept headers are set to text/xml from the REST client. When I set it to application/xml it does not get forwarded to the resource. It comes back with a 400 Bad Request. I went a little further and changed the REST resource method to consume it as text/xml. The filter forwarded it to the method but since the content is XML the String object parameter that is mapped to capture the request data is empty.There is no change in request headers when it gets forwarded.